# Spring Boots Gradle Plugin is ignoring applicationDefaultJvmArgs in the start scripts

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

The documentation of the gradle `application` plugin states that I can use `applicationDefaultJvmArgs` to configure the JVM startup parameters which are written in the start script. When using the Spring Boot Gradle plugin, I get a new distribution called `boot`, which also contains start scripts. Unfortunately they seem to ignore `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`. They contain this line:

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and POCKETKNIFE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""
```

while my original distrubtion contains this line:

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and POCKETKNIFE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-XX:+UseSerialGC" "-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10" "-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10" "-Xms32M" "-Xmx128M" "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"'
```

How can I set the JVM parameters in the Spring Boot distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out: Add this to the `build.gradle` file:

```
bootStartScripts {
    defaultJvmOpts = project.applicationDefaultJvmArgs
}
```

It still looks like a bug to me, especially since the `bootRun` task uses the `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`.